# Getdate()+7 on a bigint column

Tags: sql-server

I try to alter a stored procedure on SQL Server to add this

```
Insert into table (column1, .., columnDate)
VALUES (@ID, .., getdate()+7)
```

But my `columnDate` is `BIGINT` instead of `smalldate`.

What should I do to add this +7 days to a bigint columnDate?

Comment: columnDate is BigInt that keeps date in what format ?

Answer (score 0):

you can use convert type 112

```
Select convert(bigint, convert (nvarchar(10),dateadd(day,7,getdate()), 112))
```

In your case

```
Insert into table (column1, .. columnDate)
VALUES(@ID,.. convert(bigint, convert (nvarchar(10),dateadd(day,7,getdate()), 112)))
```

Answer (score 0):

If that bigint should contain an [EPOCH time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time), then you could use:

```
cast(datediff(second, cast('1970-01-01' as date), cast(GetDate()+7 as date)) as bigint)
```

It'll generate a big number like `1497916800`

Which can be transformed back to a date like this:

```
select DATEADD(second, cast(1497916800 as bigint), '1970-01-01')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Insert into table (column1, .., columnDate)
SELECT  @ID, .., cast(floor(getdate()+7) as int)
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which may provide some immediate help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its educational value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with similar, but not identical, questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.